# Loading image resources as RGB 565

Tags: android, image, memory-management, rgb

I'm trying to lower the memory usage of my app, and I noticed most of it is caused by the activities' backgrounds: in XHDPI, 720*1280*4 = 3.6Mbytes each, and Android doesn't seem to release them as soon as they're not in use anymore.

Is there any way to tell Android to load certain resource images as `RGB 565` instead of `RGB 8888` in order to save some memory on those larger images without alpha channel ?

I know this can be done programmatically, but I was wondering if this can also be done with images and backgrounds used in the activities' layouts or with `setBackgroundResource()`.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.high_scores);
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
    BitmapDrawable highScoresBg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.achievements, opts);
    findViewById(R.id.high_scores_root).setBackgroundDrawable(highScoresBg);
```

Pixels of your image will be stored on 2 bytes, instead of 4 when using ARGB_8888. 50% saved memory, but of course less quality.

This [article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/) tells us that on Android < 2.3 the images are in RGB_565 by default. However, if the image has alpha channel (PNG for instance), it will be loaded in ARGB_8888. On Android >= 2.3 all the images are loaded in ARGB_8888 by default.

Comment: Yes, as I said I know it can be done this way, but I'm looking for a way to tell Android to directly load specific layout images in RGB565 so I don't have to do it for each programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to flag a resource to be RGB_565.

The best you could do, would be to provide a subsequent data file which maps your image files to desired in-memory formats. At load time, you can check each resource ID against the file to determine if you'd like to set the BitmapFactory options to 565 or 8888.

A similar process is used by most applications that pull down image data. For example, some JPG images which have a small resolution, are assumed to be thumbnails, and loaded into memory using the 565 path. Where full-screen JPGs are allowed to load into memory as 8888.

Basically, you'll always need some level of logic in your app to set the BitmapOptions accordingly.